# LED-colour for clock

Tags: led, clock, colour

I'm making a big led-clock, and I'll use 55 LEDs per each Segment.
The clock will be 15cm high and consits of 4 Segments. That are approx. 250LEDs.

Now I'm looking for cheap LEDs which suit my purpose.

My Question:

I found greenLEDs, red LEDs and "super-red" LEDs very cheap (all the same price), but I have no idea what the difference between "red" and "super-red" is.

What exacly is super-red and which color would you recommend? The time should be good visible during the day, in the night I'll decrease the brightness by turning off and on very fast.

Comment: LED specifications are required.

Comment: READ THE DATASHEET, to get the specs for each LED, then compare.

Comment: The manufacturers define "red" and "super-red". So you need a datasheet. Alternativly get a few samples in and compare them. Some reds are deep red and some have a tiny shift to the orange them look a different colour and brighter.

Comment: Tri-colour are Green with one polarity, Red with the other, and Yellow with AC. Using modulation techniques you should be able to select both brightness and any shade of colour within that range large range. Since your effort and cost are sufficient, your results could be creatively adjustable.

Answer (score 2):

In brightly lit conditions, the human eye is most sensitive to green light, around 550 nm wavelength. On the other hand, in dim light, the eye has poor color perception anyway, but is highly perceptive to slight changes to luminosity.

Hence the recommendation would be to use green LEDs for the clock.

If the specific datasheets or part numbers of the mentioned LEDs are provided, a more detailed answer could be arrived at, regarding the two red ones.

In general, qualitative nomenclature of LEDs is largely a marketing ploy, not translating into specific behavior parameters such as luminosity.  One company's *super* is another's *ultra*.

Comment: Not 550, most sensitive to wavelengths near 555 nm, in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision#Wavelength_and_hue_detection

Comment: @ExcitingProjects Often different sources will have very minor differences in the cited wavelength when referencing human eye interaction. In my lasers class I could often find many sources that had very minor wavelength differences. 5nm is negligable though, at least in my opinion.